# Why Meteor js not execute serially on Meteor.call()

Tags: javascript, meteor, callback, meteorite, meteor-helper

I am quite new in this Meteor.js. Inside my `Template.myTemplate.onCreated()`, i am calling two server method using `Meteor.call()`. Now issue is code inside callback in Meteor.call() execute after executing remaining code inside onCreated function. Same thing happening inside **helpers** and **event**.

Is it right? or i am doing something wrong?

If it is right then is there any way to do that code will execute serially?

Example to make you understand better :

client/myTemplate.js

```
Template.myTemplate.created = function(){
    console.log('created start');

    Meteor.call('myTestMethod1', function(err, res){
        if(res){
            console.log(res);
        }
    });

    Meteor.call('myTestMethod2', function(err, res){
        if(res){
            console.log(res);
        }
    });

    console.log('created end');
}
```

server/method.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    myTestMethod1 : function(){
        return "myTestMethod1";
    },

    myTestMethod2 : function(){
        return "myTestMethod2";
    }
});
```

console:

```
created start
created end
myTestMethod2
myTestMethod1
```

Any thoughts...

Comment: I suggest you search for the words "race condition". It could help you discover what your code is doing and why.

Comment: @Kyll **race condition** is `two threads/control try to access the same data at the same time` that i got it...but what is your thought like Meteor does this to prevent **race condition**???

Comment: Well, race conditions are an ever-lasting issue when you have API calls. Meteor solves it in multiple ways... On the server, with Fibers (asynchronous code written in synchronous style). On the client, you can use reactive variables. Let me write an answer showing it.

Answer (score 0):

Calls to Meteor methods are always asynchronous when you provide a callback. See the [official documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call).

If you do not provide a callback the call will be synchronous and the rest of your code won't be executed until the call is completed.
But you may not get any result with synchronous calls.

Comment: Meteor methods only block when on the server, calls from the client can never block.

Comment: @ErezHochman you mean server API call from the client is happen synchronously and by the time of the executing the server method though it has a callback the remaining code of the function run and then callback runs.

Answer (score 0):

A way to fend off this issue is by using a reactive-variable (or dictionary such as `Session`) to know when the calls have completed. As such,

```
Session.set('method1Completed', false);
Session.set('method2Completed', false);

Template.myTemplate.onCreated(function() { //Note that you should use onCreated now
  Meteor.call('method1', function() {
    Session.set('method1Completed', true); //You could also put your result here
  });
  Meteor.call('method2', function() {
    Session.set('method2Completed', true);
  });

  Tracker.autorun(function(computation) {
    if(Session.get('method1Completed') && Session.get('method2Completed')) {
      //If we get in here it means both methods have completed
      computation.stop(); //We're done, stop observing the variables
      doStuff();
    }
  }
}
```